# Is it possible to force macOS to play audio only on the active app?

Tags: macos, audio

Is there a way to make sound come pro only one app.

Example: I have VLC and safari (YouTube). Both are playing a video but I want my speakers to only play the sound from the active app.

So if I selected safari to be active, VLC is muted and safari plays a sound.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across an answer that mentions an app called [Sound Control](https://staticz.com/soundcontrol/) ($19) that should do what you want, but I haven't tried it yet.